# php multi image upload script doesn't upload some image files

Tags: php, image, upload, image-uploading

I have an multiple image upload script, it resizes images and creates a thumbnail. for some odd reasons some images do are not going though. in this case the image size is small and it's a JPEG type file. for some reason its not going through. it works perfectly with other images. I am using the same script for single files and it uploads that image file. please help! thanks!

```
<?php require_once("../includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php 
$albumName = $_GET['album'];
$albumDate = $_GET['date'];
$albumId = $_GET['id'];
$upload_path = "/home/elevat17/public_html/images/gallery/"; //location
$images = $_FILES['userFile']['name'];
$temps = $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'];
$types = $_FILES['userFile']['type'];
$errors = $_FILES["userFile"]["error"];
if ($_FILES["userFile"]["name"]=="") {echo "You must choose a file to upload!";}
if(in_array("", $images)) {die('Select an image to upload.');}


else

{
for ($n=0; isset($images[$n]) && isset($temps[$n]) && isset($types[$n]) && isset($errors[$n]); $n++) {
if ((($types[$n] == "image/gif")

|| ($types[$n] == "image/jpeg")

|| ($types[$n] == "image/pjpeg")

|| ($types[$n] == "image/png")

|| ($types[$n] == "image/jpg")

|| ($types[$n] == "image/x-png")))


{

if ($errors[$n] > 0)

{

$content =  "Return Code: " . $errors[$n] . "<br />";

}

else

{

$content =  "Upload: " . $images[$n] . "<br />";

$content =  "Type: " . $types[$n] . "<br />";

$content =  "<br/><br/>";



if (file_exists($upload_path . $images[$n]))

{

die($images[$n].' already exists. Upload cancelled!');

}

else

{

$uploadedfile = $temps[$n];

$image = $images[$n];

$size = getimagesize($uploadedfile);

$type = $size['mime'];

$width = $size[0];

$height = $size[1];

if($height > '900' || $width > '600')

{ 

$newwidth=600; // NEW WIDTH 

$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;

$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

$filename = $upload_path.$image;



if($size[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF)

    {

        $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);

        imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

        imagegif($tmp,$filename,100);

    }

elseif($size[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)

    {

        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

        imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

        imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

    }

elseif($size[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) 

    {

        $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

        imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

        imagepng($tmp,$filename,9);

    }
crop_img(75,75);
move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile, $filename);
imagedestroy($src);

imagedestroy($tmp);

}

else

{      




}
$query = "INSERT INTO photos (photo_name, in_album) VALUES ('{$image}', $albumId)";
            if (mysql_query($query)) {header("location: edit_album.php?id={$albumId}");}




}

}

}

else { $content     =  "Invalid file"; }

}

}

?>
<?php require("../includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Please, organize your code in more readable way!

Comment: Please give more information on the image. Size, width, height, file ending

Comment: @ChristianLavie thanks i think you were on the right track it was because of the width and height of the image the code was messed up because of an if statement. fixed it. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking if the upload succeeded and are assuming it has. This is a bad way to write code. There is exactly **ONE** way for an upload to succeed, and **MANY** ways for it to fail.

You're also assuming the person doing the upload is not malicious and won't simply rename their `nastyvirus.exe` to be `cutekittens.jpg` before uploading.

At bare minimum, you need to have

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die('Upload failed with error code ' . $_FILES['userfile']['error']);
}
```

to ensure you've actually got something useful to work with, and then use something like http://php.net/fileinfo to have the SERVER determine what the file's type is.

Never EVER trust what the user sends to you.

Comment: Thanks so much i fixed the issue, the if statement where it checked the image's height and width was the problem. i didn't write the code but i was too lazy and in too much of a hurry to rewrite it :P. thanks so much. cheers